# manage.py startapp creates read-only files from within docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a django app running in a docker container. I bashed into the container and used `python manage.py startapp`. However, the created directories and files appear to be read-only. From within intellij, I am unable to edit the files. I get a popup offering to clear the readonly status, but that just gives me an error `unable to clear readonly status on the following files`.

How can I edit my files outside of the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running your container as root user. Hence you do not have the permission to edit them via your editor.

Try running your container with a regular user (for example `docker run  --user 1000:1000 whatever-you-need`).

Comment: Thanks, that's gotta be it. I just changed the permissions using chmod so all is well